# How to select 'option' name from a select box if the option name are identical under different optgroup

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can we select desired options from a `select box` if the option names are identical under different `optgroup`.( please refer the attached screen shot of html tag). I have tried the following ways, but none of them is working for me, any advise is really helpful.

```
cy.get('option[value="Select RadioButtonList"]').select("Radio buttons (Single-select)")
```

//    or

```
cy.get('#itemType').select('Radio buttons (Single-select)').should('have.value', 'Select RadioButtonList')
```

//   or

```
 cy.get('#itemType').then(function($select){
      $select.val('Select RadioButtonList')
   })
```

//   or

```
 cy.get('select').should('have.value', 'Select RadioButtonList')
```

[image: ss]

Comment: Posting the command log output would help a lot with debugging your issue.  For starters you have to chain `.select()` off of the select object.  so `cy.get('select#itemType').select('Select RadioButtonList');` may work and select the first one.  I haven't had to work with optgroups yet so I can't say for sure.  Post back with your results and the command log output and we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, this one by value got worked, appreciate your advise!  `cy.get('select#itemType').select('Select RadioButtonList')`

Comment: Good to hear, I'll add it an an answer so I can get the Internet points.

Comment: I have accepted and added the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chain `.select()` off of the select object. Selecting by value may work better.  So try this:

`cy
  .get('select#itemType')
  .select('Select RadioButtonList');`